# Programmatically changing OSGi bundle imports

Tags: java, osgi, classloader, equinox

There is a common bundle (A) in my Equinox OSGi application which is used for a common task. But bundle A imports packages from many other bundles depending on circumstance. What I mean is, When Bundle A and Bundle B are in the runtime, A should import package "com.b.package1". When Bundle A and Bundle C are in the runtime, A should import package "com.c.package2". For this I have to change the import statement in MANIFEST.MF file in bundle A manually every time I want to change the runtime. Is there a way to handle this programatically. Maybe using a custom class loader in bundle A? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why?

If bundle A acts differently depending on the existing of bundles which depend on Bundle A, then you should probably split Bundle A up into separate bundles, Bundle AC and Bundle AB, both of which have their own MANIFEST.MF. 

If I understand, that is kind of the point. You shouldn't have to perform weird Classpath trickery to get this kind of dynamic behavior, but you do need to structure your bundles properly.

Comment: +1 for @SheenaArtrip's comment. There is absolutely no good reason to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: There is a reason. Bundle A embeds hibernate and many utility classes needed for DB access. But the entity classes are in different bundles (B and C) . The entities are added to Hibernate configuration during activation phase of the bundles. Even though entities are added properly, bundle A cannot see the entity classes unless they are explicitly imported. I want to be able to add another bundle D with a different Database Entity class without manually importing it in bundle A. When I want to remove B, I should not have to manually remove import statement.

Comment: Dynamic imports solved the problem. Thanks a lot for the help :).

Comment: Dynamic imports will get you into more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me why? Or direct me to some doc explaining the problem with Dynamic imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, it's not possible to create a custom bundle class loader in a framework independent way. However, there are alternatives available.

One possible way could be using dynamic imports. Then both packages can be accessed at runtime. Making both imports optional might also work.

You should also definitely look at OSGi services for your approach (or at Declarative Services).

Comment: Thanks Gunnar. Dynamic imports were exactly what I was looking for :) http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/DynamicImport-Package

Answer (score 2):

You should consider implementing B and C as OSGi Services.

Trying to get dynamic behaviour of something that is intended to be static, could be a hint for architectural issues.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this points to architectural issues. Especially hibernate is known to require you to use dynamic imports to access your jpa entities. In upcoming versions the hibernate team promises better OSGi support but for now it is quite crappy in OSGi.

So I suggest to switch to OpenJPA or Eclipselink and use Aries JPA to create the JPA EntityManager. This way the EntityManager is created per bundle and you can inject it as a service. It also takes care of container managed persistence if you want. So you can almost use JPA like in Java EE.

See http://aries.apache.org/modules/jpaproject.html
and http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/13/Apache+Karaf+Tutorial+Part+6+-+Database+Access